# Is there a "repo forall -c ..." command to push my own modified AOSP project to a remote GitHub repository?

Tags: android, git, embedded-linux, android-source, repo

We're working with a SoM for an android embedded project. It involves writing drivers, designing apk and making an android customization from the AOSP.
With repo commands we downloaded many repositories (AOSP, NXP and SoM's manufacturer)

We started working in a develop branch:

```
repo forall -c 'git checkout -b <dev_branch_topic>'
```

We also tried with:

```
repo start <branch/topic>
```

(I'm not really sure of the difference between using repo forall .. or repo start for this goal)

We designed our manifest that includes the SoM's manufacturer manifest, at the same time it includes an AOSP manifest (that calls NXP and AOSP repositories)

Is there a "repo forall -c ..." command to push my own modified AOSP project to a remote GitHub repository?

Do we need first to create an empty folder for each repository that we would like to backup in our GitHub account?

Which repo command lets us change every "remote url field" inside the git config's files? We assume that getting in every project and changing it manually is not viable.